Foreign Key Constraint Error During Staggered Table Migration
I'm facing a foreign key constraint issue due to a timing mismatch between the migration of two related tables. Here's the scenario:
Group 1 migrates the class table at 10:00 AM, which initially contains 10 records. All 10 records are successfully migrated to the target system.
Between 10:00 AM and 10:10 AM, a new class entry (ID: 11, Name: Geography) is added to the source class table.
Group 2 starts migrating the student table at 10:10 AM. This table has 342 rows, including a student "ishan" linked to the new class entry (ID: 11, Geography).
The problem is that the target class table only has the original 10 records. When Group 2 tries to migrate the student table, it encounters a foreign key constraint error because the class entry with ID 11 doesn’t exist in the target class table.
This issue seems to be caused by the time gap between the migrations of the class and student tables, where new entries in the class table are not accounted for in the target system, leading to referential integrity issues.
How can I resolve or prevent this foreign key constraint error during the migration process? Is there a recommended approach to ensure referential integrity when migrating related tables at different times?

To resolve the foreign key constraint error during migration, either migrate the related tables simultaneously or, just before migrating the student table, update the class table to include any new records. Alternatively, temporarily disable foreign key checks during the migration and re-enable them afterward, but this requires careful manual integrity checks. It helped me once.
